# Toggle Boolean in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out how to toggle a boolean attribute from true to false in my Rails 4 app. I've read lots of similar problems in earlier versions of rails, but things have changed in the routes and other things that make those solutions different to what I need.

I have a projects model, which includes an attribute called draft. If :draft is false, I want to include a link in my show that will make :draft update to true.

I have tried several js solutions from other answers but I can't figure out the logic that I need for this.

Has anyone done this in Rails 4?

I have tried Zoran's suggestion below as follows:

Projects controller:

```
 def toggle_draft
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.draft = true
    @project.save
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end
```

Projects show:

```
  <% if @project.scope.finalise.draft %>
      <%= link_to toggle_draft_path(id: @scope.id)
  <% end %>
```

Routes:

```
resources :finalise

  patch '/toggle-draft', to 'finalises#toggle_draft', as: 'toggle_draft'
```

I have updated my schema to make a model called scope and a model called finalise. Scope belongs to projects and Finalise belongs to Scope.

I have set Scope to accept nested attributes for Finalise and Projects to accept nested attributes for Scope. I have white labelled the params in projects and scope and finalise.

I now have two partials in my Finalise view, one for draft and one for finalise. In the draft partial I have tried:

```
<% if @project.scope.draft == true %>
    <%= link_to toggle_draft_path(id: @project.scope.id) %>
<% end %>
```

In my finalise controller, I have the toggle method, adapted from that Zoran suggested:

```
 def toggle_draft
    @finalise = Finalise.find(params[:id])
    @finalise.draft = true
    @finalise.save
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end
```

above and my routes are:

```
 resources :finalises
   patch '/toggle-draft', to 'finalises#toggle_draft', as: 'toggle_draft'
```

I try to start the server to test this, but I get an error which says:

rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
   patch '/toggle-draft', to 'finalises#toggle_draft', as: ...

When i comment the route line out of finalises and try to start the server, I get a further error that says:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column finalises.scope_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "finalises".* FROM "finalises"  WHERE "finalises"."s...

My finalise table has a column for scopes_id (integer).

Thank you

Comment: show some code that you've tried and we'll help from there.

Comment: I set out Zoran's suggestion above

Comment: To resolve the `PG:UndefinedColumn` error, you must add a `scope_id` column in the `finalises` table, and run the necessary migration(s).

Comment: your syntax error is because you need an `end` after the `patch` line in your routes.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the suggestion, I have changed the route file to resources :finalises do
   patch '/toggle-draft', to: 'finalises#toggle_draft', as: 'toggle_draft'
  end but I still get this error:
  No route matches [GET] "/toggle-draft"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following to accomplish a draft toggle for your projects:

1. Expose a route for the link on your show page:

**routes.rb:**

```
patch '/toggle-draft', to: 'projects#toggle_draft', as: 'toggle_draft'
```

2. Define a `toggle_draft` in your ProjectsController:

**projects_controller.rb**

```
def toggle_draft
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.draft = true
  @project.save
  redirect_to project_path(@project)
end
```

3. Finally, in your markup for the show page you can conditionally display the link:

**projects/show.html.erb:**

```
<% if @project.draft %>
  <%= link_to 'Toggle', toggle_draft_path(id: @project.id), method: :patch %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Since it's a destructive action, I'd rather do that in `POST`. Or more RESTfully -- `PATCH`. By using `GET` one can get some special effects with caching.

Comment: Hi Zoran, I'm trying this, but get an error with the route =>  expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    get '/toggle-draft', to 'projects#toggle_draft', as:

Comment: My mistake - i forgot to include a `:` in the **routes.rb** file. I updated my answer. Take a look at the line in the routes.rb again, it should fix that error. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Zoran, thnaks for the help with the route. I still get this issue. Do you know what that might mean I need to do?
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column finalises.scope_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "finalises".* FROM "finalises"  WHERE "finalises"."s...
                                                      ^

Comment: That error seems to say that when you created the Finalize/Scope models, you may not have run the necessary database migrations - it's saying the `scope_id` column doesn't exist in the `finalizes` table.

Comment: Yes, I had it pluralised in error. I have other errors now and trying to figure those out. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks Zoran, I've got your code in my project, and it all runs, but the toggle doesn't save the boolean with the toggled answer. Is there another step to this?